# Kotlin type variance and star projection

Tags: java, generics, kotlin

I have read the book(Kotlin in Action, MEAP), documentation and articles about type projection and star projection, but still the projection seems to be written very complicated. Can someone explain in a simple way the idea behind the projection? Would be nice to have some appropriate examples.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Generics are probably the most intelectually teasing topic in every programming language that has them. If you know Java, you'll easily pick up Kotlin generics:

- type projection `<out T>` reflects to `<? extends T>` in Java.
- type projection `<in T>` reflects to `<? super T>` in Java.
- star projection `<*>` reflects to `<?>` in Java.

If you don't know Java, then read again chapter 9 from the book "Kotlin in Action". Type variances are being very well explained there. But, there seems to be an issue with the comment on listing 9.19 (pp. 251) in the part about *star projection*.

```
>>> val stringValidator = validators[String::class] as FieldValidator<String>
>>> println(stringValidator.validate(""))
false
```

They say:

> The compiler emits a warning about the unchecked cast.

That's true. The compiler emits a warning, but the next sentence at the same paragraph doesn't seem to be true:

> Note, however, that this code will fail on validation only, not when you make the cast, because at runtime all the generic type information is erased.

If that meant that the previous code snippet should have returned true instead of false, then they were wrong. The output is accuarate, but the explanation seems to be misleading or I missed to understood something.

p.s.
Here is some additional code needed to understand previous code snippet:

```
interface FieldValidator<in T> {
   fun validate(input: T): Boolean
}

object DefaultStringValidator : FieldValidator<String> {
   override fun validate(input: String) = input.isNotEmpty()
}

val validators = mutableMapOf<KClass<*>, FieldValidator<*>>()

validators[String::class] = DefaultStringValidator
```

Not sure, but perhaps all of this was an issue in the Kotlin v1.0 that was used in the book. I have tested it with v1.2.50.